# Stating a variable with cell location

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet with multiple columns and rows of data. The relevant part of the data start when there is a cell in column a with some text (eg. ident).

I am trying to use an if to go through the cells until it find the cell with "ident" and return its row number (and assign a variable to this row number)

Code I am using:

```
For Each Cell In ActiveSheet.Range("A")
            If ActiveSheet.Cells.Value = "Ident" Then
                start1 = ActiveCell.Row
                Exit For
            End If
        Next Row
```

Problem is, the cell term is giving me an error (I am probably referencing it wrong). What do I need to use after the "for each" to go through the cells in column A, in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")
    If cell.Value = "Ident" Then
        start1 = cell.Row
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

you may also consider these two further steps of improvement (from both logical and speed point of view):

- step 1

  loop only through cells with some constant text value in it

  ```
  For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
      If cell.Value = "Ident" Then
          start1 = cell.Row
          Exit For
      End If
  Next
  ```
- step 2

  use `Find()` method and avoid loops

  ```
  Set cell = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues).Find(what:="ident", lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=True)
  If Not cell Is Nothing Then start1 = cell.Row
  ```

  where you must both *always* specify values for `LookIn`, `LookAt` and `MatchValue` arguments and carefully choose them

Comment: errors in your code were: 1) `Range("A")` -> `Range("A:A")` 2) `ActiveSheet.Cells.Value` -> `cell.Value` 3) `ActiveCell.Row` -> `cell.Row` 4) `Next Row` -> `Next cell` (or simply `Next`)

Answer (score 0):

Another option for looping through the column.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Columns(1).Cells
        If cell.Value = "Ident" Then
            Debug.Print cell.Row
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```